# Spawn stdout called only after 4098 bytes output

Tags: c++, node.js

I have an executable which is made of C++ which prints data to console at least 4 times a second. I'm reading the data in node.js with spawn and this is how the code looks like

```
const ls = spawn('pump.exe', ["","xxx","yyy","zzz" ]);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Now my problem is that the output is not as smooth like it is when I run the command in Windows command prompt, it waits for 4098 bytes and `stdout` event is called only in 3 or 4 seconds.

How can I make `stdout` to print in realtime?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cout.flush();
```

... but I'd first verify if the problem is on c++ or js side.

Comment: But the output is smooth in command prompt. so i don't think its the c++ problem

Comment: @NaveenMargan `cout` is line-buffered when writing to a terminal, but not otherwise.